# How to unsend facebook message using python3

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, messaging

I googled a lot but didn't find a way to unsend the sent message in facebook using python...
All I could find was "How to send fb message using python with fbchat or selenium and so on" but I want to unsend the message...

***So, Is there any way to unsend facebook message using python with either fbchat or selenium or anything else...?***

Comment: No there is no API for that and Facebook does not allow you to interact with them in any other way.

Comment: Yes there is `client.unsend()` method. Read the documentation of `fbchat`.